# A 1st order "intermittent" differential equation defined on a disconnected open set

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $T>0$.

Let $x(t):[0,T] \to [0,1]$ be a Lipschitz continuous function with $x(0)=1$.

Let $E$ be an open subset of $[0,T]$ (with $\mu(E)< T$ for a meaningful problem).

We are given that $x(t)$ is differentiable on $E$ and it satisfies $\dot x(t)= 1-2 x(t)$ for all $t \in E$.

Furthermore, $\dot x(t)=0$ for almost all $t \in [0,T]/E$.

**does the following hold: $x(t)>1/2$ for all $t \in [0,T]$?**

I can see that it intuitively holds, but I found a difficulty in articulating a rigorous proof when $E$ is complicated (e.g, $E$ is an open set with a boundary of positive measure)

Comment: I started by contradiction. Assuming that $\exists t^*$ such that $x(t^*)=1/2$, let $t_0=\inf\{t|x(t)=1/2\}$. Then $\dot x(t) \le 0$ for almost all $t \in [0,t_1]$. Hence we have $x(t)$ strictly decreasing on $[0,t_1]$. Next, I need to show that $x(t)$ cannot decrease to $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x$ is Lipschitz, it is absolutely continuous, and $x(t) = x(0) + \int_0^t \dot{x}(s)\; ds$.   Noting that $\dot{x}(s) = (1 - 2 x(s)) I_E(s)$ for almost every $s$ (where $I_E$ is the indicator function of $E$), we have
$$ x(t) = x(0) + \int_0^t (1 - 2 x(s)) I_E(s)\; ds $$

EDITED: Let $$m(t) = \int_0^t I_E(s)\; ds$$ i.e. the Lebesgue measure of $[0,t] \cap E$, and
$$y(t) = \frac{1 + \exp(-2 m(t))}{2} $$
Then $y(t)$ also has $y(0)=0$ and $\dot{y}(s) = (1 - 2 y(s)) I_E(s)$ for almost every $s$ (i.e. every member of $E$ and every Lebesgue point of $E^c$), and the same argument shows
$$ y(t) = y(0) + \int_0^t (1 - 2 y(s)) I_E(s)\; ds$$
Thus $z(t)=x(t)-y(t)$ satisfies
$$ z(t) = -2 \int_0^t z(s) I_E(s)\; ds, \ z(0)=0 $$
So $$\max_{0 \le s \le t} |z(s)| \le 2 t \max_{0 \le s \le t} |z(s)|$$
which for $0 < t < 1/2$ says $\max_{0 \le s \le t} |z(s)|=0$, i.e. $z(s)=0$  for $0 \le t < 1/2$.  Repeat the argument on each interval $[n/2, (n+1)/2]$ to get
$z(s)=0$ on $[0,T]$, i.e. $x(t) = y(t)$, and in particular $x(t) > 1/2$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I might be slow at 1am but I didn't understand how $x(t)>1/2$ follows from this argument. also, what is non-decreasing? $x(t)$ should be non-increasing.